# Prediction of event in time series with multiple sample series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, panel-data, rare-events

So here's the problem:

I am dealing with about 200 time-series of banking accounts that have drawn on a credit at some point. I know the point when they got the credit (let's call this point t(credit) ) and know the account balance from t(0) - t(credit)

Now I want to build a model which tells me, how high the chance for taking a credit is for other accounts that have not taken one so far.

In other words: I want to know at which point a customer takes on a credit.

I know that this is not realy a multiple time series, since the series don't effect each other.

The closest slution so far is described in this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271539746_Time-series_event-based_prediction_An_unsupervised_learning_framework_based_on_genetic_programming) which is not totaly reproducable to me in some parts.

My questions:

What kind of statistical test/ machine learning algorithm can solve the problem? Is there an R-Package that might help me?

https://csvshare.com/view/4ydm2-Lyr

Here's the data for the first 5 IDs, each one is a single time-series. The third column gives information about wether the income is due to a credit. Some IDs might have taken on more then one credit, but to keep it simple, I'm only interested in the last one. (for some reason the IDs changed, but the series are still in correct order)